# How to convert string into binary

Tags: python, string

I want to convert a string into binary codes, I try to use

```
test_str = "a"

res = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)
```

and I get 1100001, but I don't need the first two bits '11' which is used to distinguish capital and lower, I only need '00001', how can I do this?

Comment: Not only one letter, but more, like 'abcdef'

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first two digits like this

```
res = res[2:]
```

Comment: But if I have more alphabets like 'abfg', how to do that? Sorry I didn't make it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use res[2:] which will clip off the first two characters.

Comment: But if I have more alphabets like 'abfg', how to do that? Sorry I didn't make it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a slice to remove the first two chars `[2:]` and apply this for every char of the string

```
def binary(value):
    return ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b')[2:] for i in value)

print(binary('a'))  # 00001
print(binary('b'))  # 00010
print(binary('ab')) # 0000100010
```